# Availability of Narrow band IoT modules or chipsets

Tags: hardware, protocols, wireless

The [Narrow-Band IoT](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NarrowBand_IOT) radio protocol seems to have been around for a few years, but I'm struggling to identify any manufacturers of devices that are actually available to buy (either from traditional distribution or developer component suppliers). I've seen plenty of discussions of the protocols and some field-trial roll outs, but nothing that seems quite prime-time.

I found some module like Quectel’s BC95 NB-IoT, SARA‑N2 NB-IoT, Sequans Monarch, FourGee-1160 on the Internet but I could not find those price and supplier.

Should I be looking for anything else similar, or is this technology still in development?

Comment: It will probably apply to the other companies as well. Here are the [distributors](http://www.quectel.com/company/distributors.aspx) of Quectel for example from their site. It is a list of e-mail addresses actually, and the easiest way to get the needed information is to contact them. (Quectel was quite helpful for me.I have looked for a particular module which was no longer manufactured and I wanted to buy some last pieces of them in Europe. So I made contact and they discovered for me that there are some left at their distributor in the Netherlands. Then I could contact the distributor.)

Answer (score 5):

It is still early days for NB-IoT and any hands-on with NB-IoT that is outside the large companies is only happening in lab and innovation environments. Mobile operators, such as Vodafone, and chipset manufacturers are actively developing technology and testing it. It's not mainstream enough yet for most developers to be able to try it out. There is [one lab in the UK operated by Vodafone and Huawei](http://www.vodafone.com/content/index/what/technology-blog/nb-iot-will-connect.html).